# how to live reload gulp.js browsersync on dynamic content change

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

I have setup gulp.js to live reload in my browser. First of all here's how my gulpfile looks like

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:5000",
        files: ["public/**/*.*", "views/**/*", "server.js"],
        port: 7000,
    });
});
```

now whenever I change something in my `views/` or `public/` directory the live reload works. However, whenever I tried to change something in my `server.js` the live reload will not work. Not sure what it is doing this. Please point me to the right direction. Thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
browserSync.init({
    files: ["public/**/*.*", "views/**/*"],
    port: 7000,
    server: 'server.js'
});
```

Comment: I get the following error message
Invalid config. You cannot specify both server & proxy options.

Comment: Edited, hopefully that will work. AFAIK the `proxy` param is only required if you have a running server separately. More details on your setup (`server.js`, how you are running that) will help clarify the issue.

Comment: not quite working still. gives me canno get /

here's the link to the gulpfile. if that any use.

https://github.com/Shadid12/nodedevkit/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: Your `watch` task is what's doing the file watches, lines 24-27.